# How do I access gparted during live usb installation.

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, gparted

I have installed Ubuntu using a usb and everything was fine until i had to restart my computer.It had the booting error. My computer is a toshiba. I tried looking at my bootings and the usb was on top. I also tried multiple things but have not worked. I heard that accessing gparted to access the boot flag might help me. But I dont know where to find it. please help.

Comment: or just any way that could fix the boot error

Comment: a picture of that error screen is much more helpful

Comment: Unless you did something drastic, its unlikely that's your problem. You might want to edit you question to include whether you are dual-booting with windows (and version) or it you did a complete install of ubuntu and which option you chose during install.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, you need to get the Ubuntu installation disk you used to install Ubuntu on the USB and boot it up. Then, click on Try Ubuntu. When the desktop loads up, head over to the terminal and type in `sudo apt-get install gparted gpart`. If asked, hit y followed by return. Then, launch gparded with `sudo gparted`. After gparted loads, click on GParted on the top menubar, Devices, and the USB device you installed Ubuntu on. Then, unmount the partition by rightclicking on the partition and then hitting "Unmount". Then, right click again on the partition and click on "Manage Flags". Finally, click on the boot flag option and press close. The boot partition should now have the needed boot flag.

Comment: `gparted` is already installed in the installation usb. You can just run graphically with no password when in the live environment. (And the cmd line command for gparted is `gparted-pkexec`

Comment: Gparted can also be run by the command gparted. I didn't know that gparted was already on the install disk. Thank you for that. :-)

Comment: Since you're already root in the live environment, either command is fine.  But after install use gparted-pkexec. This is what the .desktop graphical launcher actually runs. It makes the authorization is run properly without the problems from running a graphical program with sudo. Glad it worked out.